# Visual Studio 2010 not compatible?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, visual-studio-2010

The Windows 8 upgrade setup says that Visual Studio 2010 would not be compatible, but that there is a solution available. 
What does 'not compatible' mean in this case? I had VS 2010 running in the preview version just fine.
What will be the consequences of the upgrade?

Comment: Did it give any details of the solution? It sounds like there's just an update or something needed.

Comment: I just tried the upgrade assistant and got the same message. It says "Go to the app website for help" but without any link.

Comment: Unfortunately it just says 'a solution is available', no details.

Comment: It's not clear from the question that you already have Visual Studio 2010 installed and are upgrading to Windows 8. Everything I've found indicates that VS2010 will install happily so it's not obvious what your problem is.

Comment: @ChrisF for everyone who tried the upgrade setup, it is clear what I mean. I have VS2010 installed and the upgrade setup say that it is incompatible but a solution is available, but does not point out what the solution is.

Comment: And did you manage to upgrade it in the end?

Answer (score 10):

You can upgrade to Windows 8 from Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 using a **Retail Install disc only**.

If you try to upgrade using the upgrade paths (that cost less then the retail disc) you will get presented with this kind of screen.

[image]

With some collaboration at MSDN [bug was submitted](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769074/visual-studio-2010-incompatible-with-windows-8) but the response only talked about installing GDR to improve test tools for VS2010 in Windows 8

I have spent allot of time trying to find information on this. I did not have a Windows 8 disc or upgrade key. So I got one and upgraded  <strike>[Windows 7 with Visual Studio to Windows 8](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5791/100165)</strike>. (Oh - had to delete my hard work.)  [So read it here instead.](http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/upgrading-from-windows-7-with-visual.html)

**End of the day you can just carry on with the upgrade. It does not mean it will fail. You might have to tweak some things on the other side.**

Comment: I need the pro versions of VS 2005-2012 on my development machine. Also, this does not answer what will happen through the upgrade.

Comment: Oh Right. How about uninstalling it before upgrade so that the checker passes. Then reinstall after upgrade. Pro, Enterprise.. they will all isntall.

Comment: Despite that it would be a lot of work to reinstall it (I use a lot of addons and customization), just out of curiosity I would like to know what will happen.

Comment: Did you try and upgrade? If the upgrade moans about it then you will need to uninstall it. Sorry - I know the feeling. Otherwise install a VM if you just want to try it. Make an image of you HDD incase you want to go back before upograde. Either way upgrade always = more work :(

Comment: I don't have the time to screw around uninstalling then re-installing, upgrading then only to find out that VS2010 won't install properly. This is my main dev machine not some VM.

Comment: Yes - we have 10 todo here........... ummm still if we want VS2010 on W8 we gonna have to do it like that (i think its better option using vs2012) I just ran the Upgrade assistant and moaned about VS2010 but I can still buy it.. No need to downvote me. It is "A" way of doing i

Comment: VS 2012 is not an option at the moment but thanks for posting.

Comment: Well we are getting our tech net sorted because we need to do this upgrade too. so possibly I will find another solution.. but for now.. plese un downvote me.. :0

Comment: @snowdude - You can't expect us to test it for you.  You are not even the author of this question.  You need to try it, and report the results, that is the only way I know how to solve this yourself.

Answer (score -1):

After contacting Microsoft it looks like VS 2010 does have compatibility issues on Windows 8, BUT it is usable on Windows 8. A GDR package has been released to resolve the compatibility issues:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182

Comment: Does not solve the problem of upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 8

Comment: I was answering the question posed, ie "What does 'not compatible' mean in this case?"

Comment: That fixes some test case problems. Even after the patch is applied it is still not compatible for upgrade.. And it only addresses VS2010 that was installed on Windows 8 -- not upgraded from Windows 7 to 8