# VS 2010 and windows 8 compatibility (Windows8-UpgradeAssistant)

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 2010 not compatible?](https://superuser.com/questions/493159/visual-studio-2010-not-compatible)

I tried the Windows8-UpgradeAssistant.exe prior to taking up the Windows 8 upgrade for $14.99.

It told me that VS2010 wasn't compatible.  Is it just complaining about the upgrade to the lesser Windows?  There's a hint that I should upgrade to Windows 8 Pro (which I would have thought was more compatible with VS2010).  I'm not a hard-core developer so I'm not as familiar with VS2010 and Windows requirements.

Have I guessed right or is there something more seriously wrong?  Currently running Windows 7 Ultimate.

TIA

Comment: Windows 8 isn't a "lesser Windows", choosing to install Windows 8 Core has nothing to do with it, the common features of Windows 8 and Windows 8 Pro are identical.  You do understand if you are running Windows 7 Ultimate that your applications WILL NOT be transfered over unless you use Windows 8 Pro right?

Comment: That was my guess, but I didn't know.  I presume that's because the dependencies are on componentry that aren't present unless you go to Pro.